# Add css to the table cell - HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having html which is below.

```
 <div name="sample">
     <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>
                   <span class="a"> 100</span>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <span class="a"> Align left</span>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

I want to align the first "td" as right.

I want the solution by using css.

```
div[name=sample] table tbody tr td span .a>:nth-child(odd) {
    text-align:right;
}
```

The above code right align all the cells. I want to align only the first cell. second cell should be left align

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use [`:first-child` pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) with `td` to select only the first cell.

```
div[name=sample] table tbody tr td:first-child span.a {
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it (td style is required to be visible in the demo):

```css
div[name=sample] table tbody tr td:first-child {
    text-align: right;
}

td {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <div name="sample">
     <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>
                   <span class="a"> 100</span>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <span class="a"> Align left</span>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                   <span class="a"> 200</span>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <span class="a"> Align left</span>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                   <span class="a"> 300</span>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <span class="a"> Align left</span>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```